# Running a Method for a Certain Number of Time

Tags: android

So I have this method called `PredictionEngine(int)` that I want to run a certain number of time with a certain time-delay between each run. The method goes like this:

```
private void PredictionEngine(int delay) throws Exception {

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            enableStrictMode();
            String val = null;
            try {
                if (tHighPass == 0 && tLowPass == 0 && tKalman == 1) {
                    //Magic
                } else {
                    //Magic
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            enableStrictMode();
            new DropboxTask(side_output, "Result", val).execute();
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

As obvious, I am running a network operation in the main thread as this is a research app and no client is ever going to use it.

I want this whole function to run for say a 100 times with a certain delay, say 2 seconds. The initial thought was to do this:

```
for(loop 100 times){
     PredictionEngine(int)
     Thread.sleep(2000); //sorry for StackOverflow programming.
}
```

However I don't want to block the main thread as I am reading some sensor data there. Any ideas for the same would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this is by using rxJava library, because it allow to create, modify and consume streams of events. You can implement everything in a few lines of code and modify it so operatioin will be performed in background as well.

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .take(100)
                // switch execution into main thread
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(t -> {
                    doSomethingOnMainThread();
                });
```

On the other hand, there is another solution- you can use Handler, which is usually bein used for thread communication. It has method .postDelayed() allowing you to postpone execution of task. Handler can be conveniently used along with HandlerThread. But, rxJava is more convenient and simple way to solve your problem.

Comment: In added the library and all, it says unable to find `AndroidSchedulers` class. What am I missing?

Comment: for AndroidSchedulers you should also use rxAndroid:  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'

Answer (score 1):

While creating your Handler, you can provide a looper as one of the constructors parameters that is based on different thread then the main thread:

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("Thread name", android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
thread.start();
Looper looper = thread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new MyHandler(looper);
```

Messages received by MyHandler will be processed on a separated thread, leaving the UI thread clear from interferences.

To loop on the task periodically, use something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }, i*delay);
 }
```

This way, in case you decide that the periodic tasks need to be canceled, you will always be able to invoke:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the issue as follows without blocking the main Thread 
I created the worker thread for looping and still running the *predictionEngine()* on main thread

```
MyThread t = new MyThread(2000, 3000); // delay and sleep
t.startExecution();
```

Worker thread class looks as follows

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    private int delay;
    long sleep;

    MyThread(int delay, long sleep){
        this.delay = delay;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            try {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        predictEngine(delay);
                    }
                });
                Log.i("Mtali","About to pause loop before next predict");
                sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    void startExecution(){
        start();
    }
}
```

Hop this helps!